# SSL/TLS Mutual authentication in Firefox-OS

Tags: authentication, ssl, firefox-os

I’m currently working on a project ( An application based on “Firefox OS”) and I would like to know if there is any existing API or library in Firefox OS that I can use in my application which ensures the SSL/TLS Mutual authentication?

If not, how can I configure SSL/TLS Mutual authentication in my application using Apache server, so that it can require a client Certificate and extract from this certificate  the public key ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak towards apache configs, but here's the documentation on our current implementation of the Raw Sockets proposal [0].  Note: any browser prefixed API is unstable and subject to change as the spec [1] is currently a moving target and is not yet a recommendation.  Here's a real life example where I was bitten by this [2].

The beauty of web standards is that they are open for anyone to propose changes, additions, etc.  You can find the Github repo here [3] where you can create an issue asking about client side certificate support.

At this time, I do not believe that our implementation of the spec, or the spec itself, supports the use case of client side certificates.  I've had to ponder this as I'm investigating implementing an SSH client.  A similar issue I have to investigate is how do I generate client side keys, and transport them to the remote machine.

If you have further technical questions, feel free to shoot me an email directly, my email address is listed in my profile.

[0] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCPSocket

[1] http://raw-sockets.sysapps.org/

[2] https://twitter.com/LostOracle/status/409598679889104896

[3] https://github.com/sysapps/raw-sockets

Answer (score 0):

Configuring Apache to allow mutual authentication is quite simple and the documentation on http://httpd.apache.org is quite clear.  Basically you need two certificates: the server one to install on the Apache server and then the client one, to be installed on your Firefox browser or other device.  The client certificate must be issued by one of the CAs that the Apache server knows for authentication to succeed.

This project https://github.com/amusarra/docker-apache-ssl-tls-mutual-authentication implements a complete configuration of Apache SSL / TLS Mutual Authentication